# Remove all the toolbars in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I don't want to see anything but the document itself:

[image]

I am able to get it to look like this temporarily, but as soon as I close and reopen the program, it's back that busy ol' interface:

[image]

I have `Restore last view settings when reopening documents` checked in the settings, but for some odd reason it only affects some toolbars and not the others. The sidebar seems to stay hidden, but the top bars always return, and so does the menu.

Also when I hide the menu bar, pressing `Alt` doesn't make it temporarily re-appear which is inconsistent with other Windows programs..

Comment: 1) See [this site](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/PrefRef/Windows/) for options you can set.  If it isn't listed here, it probably isn't an option.  2)  Alt key making a hidden menu appear has to be implemented by the application, it is not a system behavior.  Try "Alt-F".. or some other expected key sequence and see if it shows up.

Comment: [Permanently close the Tools pane in Acrobat Reader DC](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/acrobat/kb/disable-right-hand-pane-in-acrobat-reader.html)

Comment: That's for Reader DC, not Acrobat DC, which doesn't have that setting. Your link gave me a couple pointers to search for, however. I've tried editing `Viewer.aapp` and the registry values like described [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/keep-tools-panel-closed-on-open/td-p/10962745) and [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/how-to-permanently-close-the-tools-pane-in-adobe-acrobat-dc.html), but sadly that didn't seem to change anything.